# How to access Spring MVC model objects in Freemarker template?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, freemarker

New to Spring MVC and FreeMarker framewroks. Followed [this](http://goo.gl/2xLw5) tutorial to get started with it.
When I tried to add few more model object and access it in freemarker template. But it didn't work. I am completely clueless about accessing model objects into freemarker template.
**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index(@ModelAttribute("model") ModelMap model) {

        String amount = "Amount";
    Document xml = readProductXML();
    model.addAttribute("users", userList);
    model.addAttribute("sectionName",amount);

        return "index";
    }
```

**Freemarker**

```
<#import "spring.ftl" as spring />
   <fieldset>
      <legend>${sectionName}</legend>
  </fieldset>
</#list>
```

**Error**

```
The following has evaluated to null or missing:
==> sectionName  [in template "index.ftl" at line 28, column 67]
```

**XML**

```
<FreeMarkerUI>
    <section name="amount" label="Amount">
        <field name="firstName" label="First Name" type="text" mandatory="yes"/>
        <field name="lastName" label="Last Name" type="text" mandatory="yes"/>
        <field name="country" label="Country" type="dropdown" codeTableName="country" mandatory="no"/>
    </section>
</FreeMarkerUI>
```

Comment: The error message and the template doesn't seem to match. If `sectionName` is null, then the failing instruction should be `${sectionName}`, not `#list`. Also you need a `{` after `$`. Also `section.@amount` can't work, because the `section` element has no such attribute; you meant `section['@name="amount"']`.

Comment: So I changed ftl to `<div id="content">

  <fieldset>
    <legend>${sectionName}</legend>` just to access `sectionName` from model but it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm also not sure what's up with `@spring.xmlDocument` VS `doc`. I don't know Spring MVC, but... I suspect you don't show the source and the output together here. Like, do you still have that `#list`? Does that fail, or you actually reach the `${sectionName}` inside it?

Comment: how about now? I have removed all the references to `xmlDocument/doc`, but still can't get `${sectionName}`

Comment: OK, so you question actually is, like, you have `model.addAttribute("test", "works");` in the action, and `${test}` in the template, and it says that `test` is null or undefined. Right?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. That's my issue right now.

Comment: If you add `throw new RuntimeException("I was here");` to the `index` method, will it fail with that? Just to be sure it's actually called for that URL...

Comment: It does work for `model.addAttribute("users", userList);` and shows the list of users.

Comment: No way... you overlook something. I still don't see the actual Java action and template, so I don't know what... Maybe the `amount` variable in Java is indeed `null`, or you have typo somewhere in the name.

Comment: Can you try to look into the tutorial I referred?

Comment: please send "*exactly*" what you've "written"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got it working by changing the controller method to

```
public ModelAndView home() {
 ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
 mav.addObject("users", userList);
 mav.addObject("user", "Big Joe");
 return mav;
}
```

Comment: Changing return type of Controller to ModelAndView does solve this problem. What makes me wonder is why does it not work when Controller returns View Name(String)??? :P

Answer (score 3):

You can also do something like this Himanshu:

```
public class User {
  private List<String> users;
  private String user;

  //getters and setters
}

public ModelAndView home (){
  ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("/someurl");
  User userToReturn = new User();

  userToReturn.setUser("Big Joe");

  //get userList from somewhere

  userToReturn.setUsers(userList);

  mav.addObject("user", userToReturn);

  return mav;
}
```

Then inside your Freemarker you can access the user object simply by doing

```
<fieldset>
  <legend>${user.user}</legend>
</fieldset>
```

Or

```
<fieldset>
  <#list user.users as displayUser>
    <legend>${displayUser}</legend>
  </#list>
</fieldset>
```

You changed some of your variable names after you posted the second time, so I just combined the two posts to give the answer.

This is a very simplistic example, but if you have a lot of different parameters coming into your controller and model attributes going out, it can become a lot more useful to keep them all in one Object rather than having to define each model object for the MAV to handle.

This same object can be used with the `@ModelAttribue` annotation too

```
public ModelAndView home (@ModelAttribute User user) {
  ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("/someurl");

  //do cool and exciting stuff with the user object

  mav.addObject("user", user);

  return mav;
}
```

This can help if you want to pass in information to the controller method over and over again from the same page.

Answer (score 2):

You need to bind the name of the @ModelAttribute to be able to use it in a Freemarker expression. Change your freemarker template to:

```
<#import "spring.ftl" as spring />
<@spring.bind "model" />
<fieldset>
    <legend>${model.sectionName}</legend>
</fieldset>
```